# Como pegar o nome da classe dentro de um método no python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou criando uma classe base que mantém alguns métodos comuns para classes filhas em Python3:

```py
import abc

class Bot(abc.ABC):
    def log(self, message):
        bot     = self.__name__
        version = self.__dict__['version']
        print(f"{bot}.{version}|{message}")

class ExampleBot(Bot):
    pass
```

A intenção é que, usando herança seja possível pegar o nome da classe em que o método é chamado sem que seja necessário ficar replicando código... Quando tento fazer isso me aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in log
AttributeError: 'ExampleBot' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Mas se eu tentar chamar a propriedade `ExampleBot.__name__` direto ele me retorna o resultado esperado. O que preciso fazer pra conseguir pegar o nome da classe em que o método log foi chamado nesse contexto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O nome da classe de um objeto está disponível como `self.__class__.__name__`

O seu erro foi que `self.__name__` tenta pegar esse atributo na instância - tem esse passo a mais.

Aproveitando o ensejo, algo bem mais escondido na documentação, é se você quiser acesso explícito a classe onde o método foi definido (ou o nome dela)  - ter acesso a subclasse, que chamou o método, sempre é `self.__class__`. Se quiser a classe "fixa", onde o método for definido, basta escrever `__class__`  - sem o self, nem nada. (Essa é uma variável "mágica" que é inserida pelo Python no escopo dos métodos apenas quando ela mesma ou `super()` são usadas)

```
import abc

class Bot(abc.ABC):
    def log(self, message):
        bot     = self.__class__.__name__
        version = self.version
        log_class = __class__.__name__
        print(f"{bot}.{version}|{message}. Log class: {log_class}")

class ExampleBot(Bot):
    pass
```

(note que nesse exemplo, além de imprimir  a classe onde o "log" está definido, que era o que eu queria mostrar, mudei o acesso ao atributo "version" - pegar o valor que está em `self.__dict__["nome_do_atributo"]` é o comportamento normal do Python para atributos - e não é necessário nesse caso - se você fizer `self.version` em vez de  `self.__dict__["version"]` isso faz com que os mecanismos normais da linguagem sejam usados, e você possa ter um mixin que altera o atributo "version" dinamicamente, (usando uma `property`, por exemplo.)

Comment: Valeu moço! Era exatamente isso que eu tava precisando